# Separate cookies being stored for http://thewebsite.com and http://www.thewebsite.com?

Tags: php, mysql, cookies, authentication

My friend and I are creating a cookie-based login system using PHP and MySQL, in which when a user logs in, a cookie storing their login information is saved.  The problem is, for each URL, http://thewebsite.com and http://www.thewebsite.com, separate cookies are stored.

Is there a solution that would allow us to save the same cookie for multiple URLs, or would we have to redirect the user to http://www.thewebsite.com every time.

If so, what is an easy way of checking whether the 'www' exists in the URL, and redirecting accordingly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the `domain` parameter: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php
It exactly describes the scenario you're having.

Answer (score 3):

use the domain argument to [setcookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

*domain*

> The domain that the cookie is
>   available to. To make the cookie
>   available on all subdomains of
>   example.com (including example.com
>   itself) then you'd set it to
>   '.example.com'. Although some browsers
>   will accept cookies without the
>   initial ., » RFC 2109 requires it to
>   be included. Setting the domain to
>   'www.example.com' or
>   '.www.example.com' will make the
>   cookie only available in the www
>   subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using [`setcookie`](http://php.net/setcookie) and do not specify a domain in the *domain* parameter, `setcookie` will not set the corresponding *Domain* parameter in the *Set-Cookie* header field (this also applies to [*session.cookie_domain*](http://php.net/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-domain)).

Now if no *Domain* parameter is present, the user agent defaults the domain value to the to the request-host (see [RFC 2109 section 4.3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2109#section-4.3.1)):

> The user agent applies these defaults for optional attributes that are missing:
>
> - Domain – Defaults to the request-host.  (Note that there is no dot at the beginning of request-host.)

If there is a *Domain* parameter present, its value must begin with a dot, otherwise the user agent will reject the cookie (see [RFC 2109 section 4.3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2109#section-4.3.2)):

> To prevent possible security or privacy violations, a user agent rejects a cookie (shall not store its information) if any of the following is true:
>
> - The value for the Domain attribute contains no embedded dots or does not start with a dot.

So, as also described on the `setcookie` manual page, use `.example.com` if you want to make your cookie available on *example.com* and its subdomains, and do *not* specify a domain if you only want to make it available on the current domain.